# Removing(replacing) avtar in comments.php with some other HTML arrangements

Tags: comment-form, comments, comments-template, comment-meta

[image]

```
 <ol class="comment-list">
            <?php
                wp_list_comments( array(
                    'style'       => 'ol',
                    'short_ping'  => true,
                    'avatar_size' => 34,
                ) );
            ?>
        </ol><!-- .comment-list -->
```

This is controlling the `avatar` size →

```
'avatar_size' => 34, →
```

I want to replace this with an arrangement where inside a square box(background) I will have First letter of the name in the absence of an avatar. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`get_avatar` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_avatar/) and develop a function to return whatever avatar you want.

Comment: How? can you elaborate with the code?

Comment: Might be just easier to use a [plugin like this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-first-letter-avatar/).